# Making the math-insert command in LyX exit the created element

Tags: lyx

When using the `math-insert` LyX function to create an element that can contains other elements, the caret ends up inside that cell, and if some text is selected when the function is called, that text will also get inside that cell.

Now, this is usually a blessed behavior, but there are some occasions when I want it to behave like a `math-insert` command that inserts an element that can't contain other elements - that is, I want the inserted TeX code to replace - not contain - whatever is selected, and the caret to end up after the the element, not inside it.

For example, when I want to bind some keys to `math-insert \mathbb{R}` - a command that adds the symbol of the real numbers field. When I run this command, I don't want my caret to get inside the `mathbb` element, and I don't want anything selected to get inside either - I just want to add the real numbers field symbol, the same way I add a Greek letter.

So, is there any other function that can help me, or an argument I can send to `math-insert`, or anything else to solve that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perhaps not very elegant, but you can use the following function for the shortcut:

```
command-sequence math-insert \mathbb{R}; char-forward; char-forward;
```

`math-insert \mathbb{R}` inserts a math inset with an ℝ, and the cursor to the left of the ℝ. The first `char-forward` moves the cursor to the right of ℝ, but still within the `\mathbb{}`. The second `char-forward` moves the cursor outside the `\mathbb{}`, but it is still within the math inset. Adding a third `char-forward` will move the cursor outside the math inset.

Comment: Our Lyx-Guru ;-(

Comment: Thanks! Two char-forwards work for me, since I want the cursor to remain in the math area. Is it possible to emulate pressing the spacebar? If so, it should work much better, as a single press on the spacebar takes you directly out of the inset, so I can put longer things in there and won't have to count how many `char-forward` I need for each command...
Also, is there a way to delete the selected text(if text is selected. If no text is selected I don't want nothing to be deleted)? If so, this could solve my second problem.

Comment: @IdanArye Ah, see I misread the question a little (a common occurrence ...). No idea if one can emulate pressing space, I stumbled upon `char-forward` in [this .bind-file](http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads//LyX/keyboardShortcuts/bpeng/personal.bind) on [the LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/KeyboardShortcuts#StandardKeybindings). As for the last question, that is the default behaviour here (LyX 2) -- if I select some text and then press the keyboard shortcut, the selected text is replaced with ℝ.

Comment: @Torb that might be the default behavior if you select normal text and run the command, but if you select part of an equation and run the command, that part gets inside the `\mathbb`

Comment: @IdanArye Yes, I see. Sorry. No idea I'm afraid, haven't found any "replace" functions.