# LyX Two Function in the Same Shortcut

Tags: lyx, shortcut

Is it possible to add two functions to the same shortcut in LyX?

I use a lot of times in norm spaces, so I added a shortcut with the function:

```
math-insert \norm{}
```

and it works fine, but the cursor is after the `}` character. How can I make the cursor be between the curly brackets in the same shortcut?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36187/making-the-math-insert-command-in-lyx-exit-the-created-element/39967#39967 `char-backward` moves the cursor back one step I think

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do the same thing (with `char-left` instead of `char-backwards`, which I think are doing the same), but I didn't know I need to use `command-sequence`

Comment: I see from Help --> LyX Functions that `char-left` is slightly different, though the differences seem to apply to bidi text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible to chain commands using  `command-sequence` and separate the command with `;`.

Similar to what has done here: [Making the math-insert command in LyX exit the created element](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36187/making-the-math-insert-command-in-lyx-exit-the-created-element/39967#39967)

but with `char-backwards` instead of `char-forward`.

In this case

```
command-sequence math-insert \norm{} ; char-backwards
```